# Sql Groovy, passar o valor de um parâmetro IN

Tags: sql, groovy, grails

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
def pessoaIds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def query = "SELECT * FROM Pessoa WHERE id IN(?)"
def pessoaList = sql.rows(query, [pessoaIds])
```

Neste caso "pessoaList" retorna uma lista vazia;

```
def query = "SELECT * FROM Pessoa WHERE id IN(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)"
def pessoaList = sql.rows(query)
```

Neste caso "pessoaList" retorna ums lista com as cinco pessoas;

Pelo que eu observei, acho que não está passando a lista para a cláusula IN da query, como deve ser passado a lista para a query?

Comment: Não lembro muito de jdbc, mas utilize: `def query = "SELECT * FROM Pessoa WHERE id IN :pessoaIds"`

Comment: Já tentei utilizando uma chave igual ao exemplo que você indicou e mesmo assim não deu certo.

Comment: se voce usa grails, porque nao `Pessoa.findAllById(pessoaIds)`? ou `Pessoa.getAll(pessoasIds)`?

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira de resolver esse problema seria a seguinte:

```
def pessoaIds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
def inSql = ""

//Monta uma variável String que será os itens da lista
//pessoaIds separadas por vírgual
pessoasIds.each {inSql = inSql + it + ","}

//Retira a vírgula que sobra no processo de criar a variável acima
inSql = inSql.substring(0,inSql.lenght()-1)

//Monta a consulta, incluindo a variável acima
def query = """
  "SELECT * FROM Pessoa WHERE id IN(${inSql})"  
"""

//Como estamos fazendo query.toString(), a String será avaliada
//antes de ser passada como parametro para o método eachRow
//Parte da avaliação é interpretar a variável inSql colocando o seu
//conteúdo na String, ou seja, o valor passado para o eachRow é
//um SQL já montado e sem parametro
sql.rows(query.toString()) { row -> 
}
```

Note que não estou utilizando parametros (? ou :parametro) no SQL e isso fere os bons princípios de passagem de parametro para um SQL.

Caso isso incomode muito, uma outra maneira de resolver seria essa (ver: http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/In-operator-in-Groovy-SQL-td4768856.html):

```
def pessoaIds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
def placeholders = []

//Monta um vetor de placeholders ? (para ser usado como parametro na query)
pessoaIds.each { placeholders << '?' }

//Monta a consulta, transformando o placeholders em uma string
//separada por virgula
def query = """
  "SELECT * FROM Pessoa WHERE id IN(${placeholders.join(',')})"  
"""

//Para esse caso, estamos efetivamente passando um parametro para
//a query
sql.rows(query, pessoaIds).each { println it }
```